# How can I determine a reasonable value for pm.max_children in dynamic mode?

Tags: php, php-fpm, fastcgi

I really don't understand the purpose of this variable - what exactly is the purpose of it? To prevent the exhaustion of ram? It seems ineffective as each request could use a variable amount of ram up to the maximum.

If I need to process `10` requests that take `10MB` in memory, and `1` request that takes `1024mb` of memory concurrently. Does this mean if I only have (`1024+10*10 = 1124mb`) of memory available, I should set the max_children to `1` - because `2` potential requests could exhaust the memory if they were both using `1024mb`?

This configuration has a limitation in that I can't process `20` requests even if they would only use `10mb` each.

What happens to a new connection once the php-fpm server reaches it's `pm.max_children value`? Does it return a 502 for the new connection?